# How to use only one proxy_pass in multi-location of Nginx? And in which phase, the nginx_geo_module run?

Tags: nginx

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

location /aaa/ {
    set_header xxxx yyyy;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

location /bbb/ {
    set_header xxxx zzzz;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Sample configuration is above, I want to do some different thing in different location, but use the same backend.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of self-repeat you could put repeating part into file and then `include` it.

In your particular case that will not decrease number of lines, but you'll be able to change backend server to something else in one place instead of three. Also, usually, it's not simple `proxy_pass`, but also a bunch of `proxy_set_header` directives, so separate file would make more sense.

`geo` is not run at some particular phase. Instead it runs whenever you want to get value of corresponding variable.

Comment: Thanks. If I use `access_by_lua set $var $some_header` in `location`, and can `geo $var $war {}` work ?

Comment: Just check it. It simple